# How to tweak the text angle in some counties with tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I made the following map using tmap:

[image]

My data source: [lic_bed_sf.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5f3ewkgpm4ic9l/lic_bed_sf.csv?dl=0), and in .gpkg format [.gpkg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nrv5c7b5oj5a7t/lic_bed_sf.gpkg?dl=0)

My code is as follows:

```
  tm_shape(lic_bed_sf) +
  tm_polygons("density", 
              id = "county_name", 
              palette = "Blues", 
              border.col = "#555555") +
  tm_layout(fontfamily = "Athelas", 
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom"),
            legend.text.size = 0.8,
            legend.text.fontface = "bold",
            frame = F,
            inner.margins = c(0.12, 0.05, 0.10, 0.05)) + 
  tm_text("county_name", 
          size = 0.50,
          fontfamily = "Kefa", 
          fontface = "bold") + 
  tm_scale_bar(text.size = 0.60)
```

My questions are:

1. As you can see, some of the county names overlap, for example
   Alamance, Orange and Durham. Is there any way I can select these
   counties and adjust the text angle to the ones in the following map?
2. How to add a thick state border like the one showing in the second map?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you share the original data to reproduce your plot?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! I updated my question to include a link to my data source. Let me know if you cannot access it.

Comment: Hi! Can you share (via dropbox or whatever) the output of `st_write(lic_bed_sf, "lic_bed_sf.gpkg")`? Because it's unnecessary difficult and annoying reading a sf file saved as .csv

Comment: It's now updated and includes a .gpkg file through a Dropbox link.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The second point is quite easy and you should add `tm_shape(st_boundary(st_union(lic_bed_sf))) + tm_lines(lwd = 2))` to your `tmap` code. I'm not sure about the first question.

Comment: Woohoo, it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is extremely hacky but shows it can be done in principle. I manually added a linestring based on where the Carteret centroid was. Centroid grabbing technique inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176660/how-to-calculate-centroid-of-polygon-using-sfst-centroid).

The text won't plot at the rotated angle unless the line is also plotted (I made the line invisible with `alpha = 0`).

```
lic_bed_sf <- st_read('lic_bed_sf.gpkg')

lic_bed_sf$centroids <-
  st_transform(lic_bed_sf, 29101) %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  st_transform(., '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs')

carteretTest <- filter(lic_bed_sf, county_name == "Carteret")

carteretTest$geom <- st_sfc(sf::st_linestring(matrix(c(-76.2, -76.8, 35, 34.7), , 2)),crs = 4326)

tm_shape(lic_bed_sf) +
  tm_polygons("density", 
              id = "county_name", 
              palette = "Blues", 
              border.col = "#555555") +
  tm_layout(fontfamily = "Athelas", 
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom"),
            legend.text.size = 0.8,
            legend.text.fontface = "bold",
            frame = F,
            inner.margins = c(0.12, 0.05, 0.10, 0.05)) + 
  tm_scale_bar(text.size = 0.60) +
  tm_shape(carteretTest) + 
  tm_lines(alpha = 0) +
  tm_text("county_name", 
          size = 0.50,
          fontfamily = "Kefa", 
          fontface = "bold",
          along.lines = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for getting back. I did try auto.placement = F within tm_text(), and unfortunately it did not alter any overlap. Could you elaborate a bit more on the second method you proposed?

Comment: @celilati see edit. By the way, if it was me, i would add the rotated labels later in Illustrator (or a similar program)!